# Bash: monitoring TCP socket activity

Tags: bash

I use mpg123 to read an mp3 webradio stream (port 8000).
Sometimes, the webradio server stops but mpg123 doesn't quit. Also, if the network on my machine fails, mpg123 won't quit either.
I would like to monitor mpg123 activity using a bash script launched by cron.
Something like this:

```
tcpdump -i eth0  port 8000 2>/dev/null | head | wc -l &
sleep 5
killall tcpdump
```

If no stream is played by mpg123, the result will be 1. Otherwise, it will be > 1.

How can I get this result into a variable?
Then I could relaunch mpg123 if the streaming has failed.

Note that I can't use the timeout command and I can't write anything on my system.

Comment: Why not have it log the information: `tcpdump -i eth0  port 8000 2>/dev/null | head >> mp3log.txt` Or, you can simply write all matching packets to a tcpdump file with `-w filename` and then use that data? There are several tcpdump/pcap file parses that provide flexible output. Look at `man tcpdump`. Yes, it a bit long, but only because it has so many options that may better suit your capture needs.

Comment: Because I don't want to write anything... My system is read only.

Comment: Using tcpdump is somewhat excessive for this use case. Instead of using `mpg123` as your streaming client, I'd consider using something with better error handling for the network interaction, and piping into `mpg123` from there. At that point, you've got more options -- for instance, `curl > >(mpg123)` will return as soon as `curl` exits, whether or not `mpg123` does, letting you do cleanup from that point.

Comment: Consider my script here as well. It might help you in some way. Perhaps some minor mod might do. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/rotating-capture-files-using-tcpdump-800385/#post4804366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly

```
isitthere=$(tcpdump -i eth0  port 8000 2>/dev/null | head | wc -l & sleep 5; killall tcpdump)

if [[ $isitthere -eq 1 ]]
then
     SET FIRE TO EVERYTHING
fi
```

not sure if it'd handle the sleep 5. But can't you use a -ll switch on tcp dump so..

worth a shot.

Comment: Did you mean `&` instead of `%`? What platform are you on? On Linux and FreeBSD/OSX, `tcpdump`'s `-l` option takes no argument and has a different meaning; the OP wanted to test whether the output is _1_ or  greater.

Comment: and that was me being tired and misreading man pages with the -l. Long day.

Comment: :) The `-c <num>` option is worth a look: it exits after <num> packages have been received. The send-to-background-then-sleep approach should work, however (at least it does for me interactively).